# Reactjs - SetTimeout with state change re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm currently running into some issues whilst developing a Typescript React App.
Underneath is my current code..

But it's not behaving like I would want it to behave. :)

So what I would like to achieve is that the data with getData(depth) runs whenever the component is being loaded and afterwards every 5 seconds.

But when the Depth changes with the Dropdown.item buttons, it should re-render and the getData() should be ran with the new depth value that we just set in the state.. and keep on rendering afterwards with the new value...

I've been struggling with this, so any help is very much appreciated!!

Thank you!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const chart = () => {
  const [depth, setDepth] = useState(20);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})

//Getting the data when the app initially renders and should keep rendering every 5 seconds after that.
//When the value of the depth changes, we should stop getting the data with the old depth //value and should start a new interval of 5 seconds and just keep running with the new //depth value
//When first entering the app, this should run immediately with the initial depth state //(20)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
     //this code is not the actual code, just an example of what is running
      const data = getData(depth)
     //just fetched the new data, now setting it.. 
      setChartData(data)
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
<div>
  <div>
   <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Depth Percentage">
    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDepth(5)}>5%</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDepth(20)}>20%</Dropdown.Item>
   </DropdownButton>
  </div>
  <div>
   //Rendering the Chart here....
  </div>
</div>
  );
};

export default chart;
```

Comment: You need to put `depth` in `useEffect` dependency` array

Answer (score 1):

That's because `useEffect` hook take a second params called `dependency array`, where this dependency array is what matter for the inner callback(inisde useEffect) to access the latest values you want.

So your are not being totally truthful here, if the inner callback depends on `depth` to be in its latest update then you should include it in the dependency array

```
useEffect(() => { ... }, [ depth ]);
```

that's for the `depth` but writing this code will immediately cause problems because for each new `depth` value the inner callback will be called and the `setInterval` will re-run again (causing many many...many of intervals).

To solve this you should avoid using `setInterval` alll together in `hooks` based code.

If having interval is really important I have a suggestion for you

```
  const [intervalCount, setIntervalCount] = useState(0);
  const [depth, setDepth] = useState(20);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})


  useEffect(() => {
    // when depth change re-fetch data and set it
    const data: any = getData(depth);
    setChartData(data);
  }, [depth])


  // simulate set interval behavior 
  // each 5 s this function will be re-invoked
  useEffect(() => {

    // re-fetch data and set it
    const data: any = getData(depth);
    setChartData(data);

    // wait 5 s before cause a re-render
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIntervalCount(count => count + 1);
    }, 5000);

  }, [intervalCount]);
```

---

Updated: After rading from Dan Abramov [blog](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

you can find a better elegant solution that use `setInterval` and `hooks`

### Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks

He made a custom hook called `useInterval`

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Usage be like

```
  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: It will run into infinite loop. Because when you will call `setIntervalCount(count => count + 1);` you are updating `intervalCount` which is in dependency array and hence again `useEffect` will run and again..... And also for each `intervalCount` you will be creating one more instance of `setTimeout` and then there will be many more setTimeout instance will run

Comment: Hello Louay! Thank you for helping out. 
As you suggest, using setInterval isn't great in hooks based code, what do you suggest to tackle such a problem?

Comment: Ah, you are right... I'll try another way today and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems inside your code:

1. Micro tasks can see values only in the scope of the callback function and capture rest on the first call only;
2. You need to inform react that should recall your fetch function with the updated values.

So your code should become (if you want to do it that way):

[Edit on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-gates-y9n6l2?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Chart = () => {
  const [depth, setDepth] = useState(20);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  //Getting the data when the app initially renders and should keep rendering every 5 seconds after that.
  //When the value of the depth changes, we should stop getting the data with the old depth //value and should start a new interval of 5 seconds and just keep running with the new //depth value
  //When first entering the app, this should run immediately with the initial depth state //(20)
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (intervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      //this code is not the actual code, just an example of what is running
      const dataValue = { depth };
      console.log("Captured dataValue in the interval:", dataValue);
      setData((prev) => [...prev, dataValue]);
      //just fetched the new data, now setting it..
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [depth]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setDepth(5)}>5%</button>
        <button onClick={() => setDepth(20)}>20%</button>
        <ul>
          {data.map((value, index) => (
            <li key={index}>Current depth for fetch: {value.depth}%</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```